# How to list all the files that are in TFS GIT repo using REST API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk, azure-devops-rest-api

All,
I am trying to get the list of all the files that are in a particular repo in TFS GIT using REST API.
I found the below one but it only display the contents of the specific file name mentioned after "scopePath=/buld.xml", it only display the contents of file build.xml.

But I am trying, only to list all the files that are in a particular repository with out mentioning the particular file name.

Please help me.

https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?items?scopePath=/&api-version=4.1

Answer (score 6):

You can use the api below:

```
https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?recursionLevel=Full&api-version=4.1
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Cece, I tried the one you suggested its not working I used to different API version like 4.0 also still its not working

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? What error did you get? I'm testing with VSTS and it works.

Comment: I am using Version 16.122.27409.2 and its on premise TFS, I am not getting any error but I am not getting what I am looking for. Below is the info I am getting.
"count":1,"value":[{"objectId":"id","gitObjectType":"tree","commitId":"ID","path":"/","isFolder":true,"url":"https://URL/_apis/git/repositories/repodi/items//?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"}]}

Comment: Please double check whether you specify the correct `project` and `repositoryId` in  the api. I just tested with TFS 16.131.27701.1, it also worked. I've added a screenshot for your reference.

Comment: Thanks @CeceDong-MSFT - this did help me. I have the same issue as OP - and I will only see the "/" folder. But If i put the file name simply to the URL I am able to get the files (but not able to list them) e.g. .../items/My_Project.sln?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None

Answer (score 3):

Also that could be achieved using VisualStudioOnline libs (at the date of writing comment it becomes AzureDevOps): Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.

First, you need to create [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts). Then just use code below:

```
VssBasicCredential credintials = new VssBasicCredential(String.Empty, "YOUR SECRET CODE HERE");
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://yourserverurl.visualstudio.com/"), credintials);
GitHttpClient client = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

List<GitRepository> repositories = await client.GetRepositoriesAsync(true); // or use GetRepositoryAsync()
var repo = repositories.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == "Some.Repo.Name");

GitVersionDescriptor descriptor = new GitVersionDescriptor()
{
    VersionType = GitVersionType.Branch,
    Version = "develop",
    VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None
};

List<GitItem> items = await client.GetItemsAsync(repo.Id, scopePath: "/", recursionLevel: VersionControlRecursionType.Full, versionDescriptor: descriptor);
```

Under the hood it's using the REST API. So if you try the same effect using c# lang, better delegate it to lib.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the items endpoint first, which gives you an objectId (the gitObjectType should be "tree"):

```
http://{tfsURL}/tfs/{collectionId}/{teamProjectId}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?recursionLevel=Full&api-version=4.1
```

Then call the trees end point to list the objects in the tree:

```
http://{tfsURL}/tfs/{collectionId}/{teamProjectId}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/trees/{objectId}?api-version=4.1
```

test